# How to Copy from Clipboard to blank ag-grid (no rows present in the grid)

Tags: angularjs, clipboard, copy-paste, ag-grid

Copying values from clipboard to ag-grid is possible when row(s) are present, my requirement is to paste into a blank ag-grid.

From [Angular documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-clipboard/):

> **Paste from Clipboard**
>
> Paste to clipboard can only be done in the following ways:
>
> Press keys Ctrl+V while focus in on the grid with **a single cell selected**. The paste will then proceed starting at the selected cell if multiple cells are to be pasted.
>
> Press keys Ctrl+V while focus in on the grid with **a range of cells selected**. If the selected range being pasted is larger than copied range, it will repeat if it fits evenly, otherwise it will just copy the cells into the start of the range.

Do we have a solution for this?

Comment: @bhargav-rao I have edited the question to be more specific to the problem, can you remove it from hold.